# BottomSheetBehavior conflicto de scroll con WebView

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy usando BottomSheetBehavior, dentro de el tengo un fragmento, el cual a su vez contiene un webview.
El problema surge cuando deseo hacer scroll en el webView, en este caso se activa el desplazamiento de BottomSheetBehavior.

**Actividad que contiene el BottomSheetBehavior**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/cont_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
            
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/cont_frame"
                android:name="com.testlab.wexb.PanelFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>
            
        </FrameLayout>
        
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity

```
val bottomSheetBehaviorPlayer = BottomSheetBehavior.from(cont_frame_layout)

        bottomSheetBehaviorPlayer.apply {
            peekHeight = 110
            this.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        }
```

**Fragmento mostrado por el BottomSheetBehavior**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PanelFragment">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </WebView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Nota**
Deseo que el scroll del webview se comporte de forma normal y cuando se detecte que la pagina esta en scrollY = 0 , se active el desplazamiento de el BottomSheetBehavior.

//scrollY = 0
lo detecto con una interfaz desde JavaScript

**Encontré esto**

```
webView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
```

permite que el webview pueda realizar el scroll de forma normal, sin embargo a su vez también se anula el desplazamiento de el BottomSheetBehavior.
Entonces he tratado de activarlo y desactivar según lo deseo, por ejemplo, si detectada que scrollY era 0 se desactive sino que se active, sin embargo no funciona, ya que no se activa automáticamente o a veces ni siquiera se activar, es decir "SI SE AGREGA AL INICIO FUNCIONA COMO DEBE", pero si se intenta cambiar una vez cargada la pagina osea mientras ya se esta interactuando , no funciona al instante o simplemente no funciona.
Supongo que es por que webview no puede realizar ese cambia al instante por que es muy significativo, ya que cuando colapso el BottomSheetBehavior y lo dejo por un momento colapsado, al expandirlo y hacer scroll nuevamente parece funcionar.

**Una solución que he visto en muchos ejemplos es usar NestedScrollView** , sin embargo no se donde colocarlo, he intentado en diversos lugares pero no obtengo resultado,  este problema también se presenta cuando en lugar del webview, hay un recyclerView o algo similar que implique algo deslizable.

Actualizacion:
Encontré [un ejemplo muy completo](https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet), esta en java, voy a revisarlo

Answer (score 0):

Luego de haber probado distintas cosas, y sin tener resultado [encontré](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md)   `isHideable` ,

> si esta hoja inferior se puede ocultar arrastrándola hacia abajo

Sin embargo esto funciona solo para ocultar el BottomSheet cuando esta en estado colapsado, es decir permite que se pueda pasar de colapsado a oculto, entonces tuve que jugar con `peekHeight`  para lograr lo que deseaba.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = 2000  //valor alto para que se ocupe toda la pantalla
bottomSheetBehavior.isHideable = false // impide que se pueda desplazar el bottomSheet
```

Cada vez que se expande el bottomSheet, configuro su propiedad `peekHeight` con un valor alto, para que ocupe toda la pantalla simulando un estado de expandido, también cambio la propiedad `isHideable`, para impedir que el se desplace y a su vez el scroll de webview funcione como debería.
Entonces cuando necesitaba que se desplace hacia abajo detectaba con JavaScript `scrollY = 0`, para configurar `isHideable = true`, así cada vez que se llega nuevamente al inicio de la pagina, el bottomSheetBehavior comienza a desplazarse como lo hace en diferente aplicaciones.

Se que esta no es un implementación  correcta, pero funciona para lo que necesito.
Es importante señalar que usar `peekHeight` como un valor máximo, para simular un estado de expandido como lo hice, puede ocasionar problemas en las animaciones o simplemente no es conveniente usarlo de esa manera, muchos tutoriales usan nestedscrollview o anulan los eventos táctiles, también se usa bottomsheetdialog el cual tiene propiedades que ofrecen un mejor control con respecto al desplazamiento, [aquí un ejemplo](https://github.com/nishantpardamwar/BottomSheetWebViewSample) de lo que quería realizar pero usando un  bottomsheetdialog, "no funcionan con bottomsheetbehavior ya que usa propiedades que este no tiene" .

Espero no haber hecho algo desastroso soy un novato, toda la explicación es acerca de lo que puede entender, espero que pueda servir como una solución rápida para alguien, realmente no entiendo por que no existe una propiedad como `isHideable` para desencadenar el desplazamiento desde su estado expandido, talvez no la encontre.